# Redirect if the user is logged in

Tags: symfony

I am building a web application with Symfony 2, using the FOSUserBundle bundle.
Users create an account, login and start using the application.

What I want to achieve now is to have the user redirected to their account from any page they may be at if they are logged in.
This includes:

- if they get back to the login page
- if they get back to the registration page
- if they go to the homepage of the website
- once they confirm their email
- once they reset their password

Basically the code would be something like this:

```
$container = $this->container;
$accountRouteName = "DanyukiWebappBundle_account";
if( $container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ){
    // authenticated (NON anonymous)
    $routeName = $container->get('request')->get('_route');
    if ($routeName != $accountRouteName) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($accountRouteName));
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know where that code should go.
It should be executed for any request. In Symfony 1 I would have used a filter.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
<?php

namespace Danyuki\UserBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LoggedInUserListener
{
    private $router;
    private $container;

    public function __construct($router, $container)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }    

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $container = $this->container;
        $accountRouteName = "DanyukiWebappBundle_account";
        if( $container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ){
            // authenticated (NON anonymous)
            $routeName = $container->get('request')->get('_route');
            if ($routeName != $accountRouteName) {
                $url = $this->router->generate($accountRouteName);
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in the services.yml file of my bundle:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.logged_in_user_listener:
            class: Danyuki\UserBundle\Listener\LoggedInUserListener
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
            arguments: [ @router, @service_container ]
```

Comment: It's not recommend to inject the container in a service, you may inject the security.context service.

Comment: @benjamin It's even simpler than that. As @dan needs the request object, he could retrieve it from the event via `$event->getRequest()`.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11506088/838733, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event or https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/KernelEvent.php

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this solution if you want to just check once:

There is an event triggered each time there's a successful login being done. 
**The event is named:**

> security.interactive_login

In order to subscribe to this event, you have to create a service container with your created class let's say "LoginListener.php" and inject the tag "kernel.even_listener" with the event "security.interactive_login":

```
<service id="mylogin.success.listener" class="path\to\class\LoginListener">
   <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" method="onLoginSuccess" />
</service>
```

**in LoginListener:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

public function onLoginSuccess(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
   if ($this->_security->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
      //your code here...
   }
}
```

you can also add other dependencies and inject it to the constructor, in my case I had to inject security, session and container:

```
public function __construct(SecurityContext $security, Session $session,            ContainerInterface $container) {

}
```