# Symfony2: Getting Route in Page Load Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get the route in a page load even listener?

I have the following code in services.yml:

```
    page_load_listener:
    class: Acme\MainBundle\EventListener\PageLoadListener
    arguments: [@security.context, @session]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController, priority: 64 }
```

In the PageLoadListener class I have the corresponding method:

```
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {

        // Some code I need to execute that needs the route arguments

    }
```

The problem seems to be that the route and arguments are not available. What am I missing?

**Which event would I need to pass to pick up the route and it's arguments?**

Thanks,

JB

Answer (score 40, accepted):

All kernel events extend [`KernelEvent`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/KernelEvent.php), which means you can simply acess the `Request` object via `$event->getRequest()`.

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // Matched route
    $_route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');

    // Matched controller
    $_controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller');

    // All route parameters including the `_controller`
    $params      = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');
}
```

If you'd like to get plain route attributes, simply filter out all the elements prefixed with "_".

Choosing the proper event to listen to depends on your specific use case.

Comment: That's the ticket, @gilden. _route and _controller are populated, the only thing that's empty is the _route_params attribute, although the ParameterBag for the Request object seems to contain the route parameter. I'd have to query it specifically, but it'll work. Would you happen to know why _route_params would not be present?

Comment: I'm seeing references to _route_params having been introduced to Symfony 2.1, which looks like is still in beta. I'm using the stable 2.0.15, so I'll work around that. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction, @gilden.

Comment: @jbsound sorry, I keep forgetting I'm using 2.1.* for one project. You could try `var_dump`-ing `$request->attributes->all()` - the attributes should be in the parameter bag for 2.0.* as well.