# Symfony check for url segment

Tags: symfony, routes

What is the best way to check for a url segment?

I have an event listener that checks if the user has completed their account if not they will be redirect to the account complete page.

This works but it also redirects them even if they are viewing the public facing site.

So I would like to check if the first url segment is 'admin' eg www.domain.com/admin.

Thanks

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505287/symfony2-getting-route-in-page-load-event-listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not works depending environment (example : front_dev.php/admin)

But you can do this

```
$cleanedUrl = str_replace('app_dev.php/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$cleanedUrl = str_replace('app.php/', '', $cleanedUrl);
    $path = parse_url($cleanedUrl, PHP_URL_PATH);
    if (substr($path, 0, 6) === "/admin") {
        echo 'ok';
    }
```

I'm not shure that is the best solution, but it should works

Comment: omg using symfony on the one hand and superglobals and str_replace on the other hand ...

Comment: As I said in the post, I just gave a fast solution that works. But it's not the better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
if (substr( $path, 0, 6 ) === "/admin") {
    //do something
}
```