# Symfony2 redirect for event listener?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a kernel event listener setup (kernel.controller) to redirect the user if he's not logged in. The event listener is succesfully getting called, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to redirect. Here's what I got:

```
$cont = $event->getController('testpost');
$event->setResponse($cont);
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent::setResponse()
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't set a response to a `FilterControllerEvent` object. You need to listen for the `kernel.request` event because its `GetResponseEvent` object has the `setResponse()` method:

```php
$route = 'route_name';

if ($route === $event->getRequest()->get('_route')) {
    return;
}

$url = $this->router->generate($route);
$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
$event->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Im still getting the `call to undefined method setResponse`, is there a class/file i should be including?

Comment: Have you changed the parameter type to `GetResponseEvent`? And do you reallly listen for `kernel.request`? Please double-check it.

Comment: Ok turns out i was on kernal.controller, so i switched it kernal.request and it redirects with error `ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to... must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent`

Comment: Ok ok, i changed the parameter to getresponseevent but now theres a redirect loop. (because every page load does the setResponse). Is there a way to do 'setResponse but skip listeners?'

Comment: Updated the answer. BTW, why are you doing this? Isn't your use case covered by the default Symfony Security behavior?

Comment: Yeah, but im using symfony mostly as an API as opposed to an actual website, therefore im building the security myself to have more flexibility

Comment: Where does the `$this->router` come from?

Comment: The router can be injected in the listener as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10512631/133717)

Answer (score 96):

If you wanna redirect from `FilterControllerEvent` you should use this one:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    // do something
    $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    });
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  I needed to redirect under certain conditions, one of which was when a particular controller had been routed. The onKernelRequest event was called before it actually routed the controller so I could not put the logic there.

Comment: This throws a "Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in ..." for me

Comment: @JuliusF Are you sure that error is thrown before redirect? Did you look at profiler?

Comment: @NHG already resolved, it turned out thaht $redirectUrl was a RedirectResponse Object too. Which is weird, because it always to pass a RedirectResponse into a new RedirectResponse object. Anyway. It was may fault.

Comment: This method would also work with a regular `Response` for anyone wondering

Comment: How do you generate the URL based on a route within this listener?

Comment: @Luke you can simply inject `router` service and generate this url.

Answer (score 4):

More ore less clear way to redirect on 'kernel.controller' event

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    /* @var $controller \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller */
    $controller = $event->getController()[0]; // PHP 5.4 or $controller = $controller[0];

    throw new HttpException(307, null, null, array('Location' => $controller->generateUrl('homepage')));
}
```

Answer (score -8):

This ain't no way to go, my friend. You should use a default Symfony Security to cover that for you...