# $this->forward looses the user's requested route?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, request, forward

I want to redirect admins to `/admin` and members to `/member` when users are identified but get to the home page (`/`).

The controller looks like this :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_admin_homepage'));
    }
    else if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_member_homepage'));
    }
    return $this->forward('AppHomeBundle:Default:home');
}
```

If my users are logged in, it works well, no problem. But if they are not, my i18n switch makes me get a nice exception :

> The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes in
>   "AppHomeBundle:Default:home.html.twig".

Line that crashes :

```
{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}
```

If I look at the `app.request.get('_route_params')`, it is empty, as well as `app.request.get('_route')`.

Of course, I can solve my problem by replacing `return $this->forward('AppHomeBundle:Default:home');` by `return $this->homeAction();`, but I don't get the point.

> Are the internal requests overwritting the user request?

Note: I'm using `Symfony version 2.2.1 - app/dev/debug`

## Edit

Looking at the Symfony's source code, when using `forward`, a subrequest is created and we are not in the same *scope* anymore.

```
/**
 * Forwards the request to another controller.
 *
 * @param string $controller The controller name (a string like BlogBundle:Post:index)
 * @param array  $path       An array of path parameters
 * @param array  $query      An array of query parameters
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 */
public function forward($controller, array $path = array(), array $query = array())
{
    $path['_controller'] = $controller;
    $subRequest = $this->container->get('request')->duplicate($query, null, $path);

    return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
}
```

By looking at the [Symfony2's scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) documentation, they tell about why request is a scope itself and how to deal with it. But they don't tell about why sub-requests are created when forwarding.

Some more googling put me on the event listeners, where I learnt that the subrequests can be handled ([details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#internal-requests)). Ok, for the sub-request type, but this still does not explain why user request is just removed.

My question becomes :

> Why user request is removed and not copied when forwarding?

Comment: Rather you should to use event listener for this functionality.  Event listener can handle ie case when user with ROLE_USRR try open home page for ROLE_ADMIN users. You can do that by creating FilterControllerEvent Listener and redirect from this to specific controller/action. I hope that this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916439/symfony2-redirect-for-event-listener/16167953#16167953

Comment: Actually, if a user accesses a `ROLE_ADMIN` page, firewall throws 403. And an admin can access `ROLE_USER`'s pages. Anyway this question is more general: I can switch from a controller or another one according to an interface implementation for example, and `forward` looks good for such jobs. If `forward` update the request, I really don't understand in which case it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

So, controller actions are separated part of logic. This functions doesn't know anything about each other. My answer is - single action handle kind of specific request (e.g. with specific uri prarams). 
From SF2 docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#requests-controller-response-lifecycle):

> 2 The Router reads information from the request (e.g. the URI), finds a
>   route that matches that information, and reads the _controller
>   parameter from the route;
>
> 3 The **controller from the matched route is
>   executed** and the code inside the controller creates and returns a
>   Response object;

If your request is for path `/` and you wanna inside action (lets say `indexAction()`) handling this route, execute another controller action (e.g. `fancyAction()`) you should prepare `fancyAction()` for that. I mean about using (e.g.):

```
public function fancyAction($name, $color)
{
    // ... create and return a Response object
}
```

instead:

```
public function fancyAction()
{
    $name = $this->getRequest()->get('name');
    $color = $this->getRequest()->get('color');
    // ... create and return a Response object
}
```

Example from sf2 dosc:

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    $response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'color' => 'green',
    ));

    // ... further modify the response or return it directly

    return $response;
}
```

Please notice `further modify the response`.

If you really need request object, you can try:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // prepare $request for fancyAction

    $response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array('request'  => $request));

    // ... further modify the response or return it directly

    return $response;
}

public function fancyAction(Request $request)
{
    // use $request
}
```