# symfony Can't retrieve route gets lost when forwarding

Tags: symfony, controller, routes, request, forward

Supose three paths

- /first/action/{argument} #where argument can be empty
- /second/action/{argument} #where argument is required
- /third/action/{argument} #where argument is required too

Supose a Controller with three actions

```
public function firstAction(Request $request, $argument=null){
    $route_params = (array) $request->attributes->get('_route_params');
    $argument=(empty($argument) ? $route_params['argument'] : $argument;
    return new Response('This was the argument'.(string)$argument);
}

public function secondAction($argument){
    return $this->forward('Bundle:Controller:first',array('argument'=>$argument));
}

public function thirdAction($argument){
     return $this->forward('Bundle:Controller:first');
}
```

When loading following urls:

- http:// localhost/first/action/passed
- http:// localhost/second/action/forwarded
- http:// localhost/third/action/forwarded_too

obtained results were:

- 'This was the argument passed'
- 'This was the argument forwarded'
- 'This was the argument'

After checking if route persisted through forwarding, my surprise was to realize that "route get lost from Request attributes ParameterBag after forwarding".

Is there any other way to retrieve the request matched route with arguments?

Why route doesn't persist through forwarding?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I was looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16402367/1400467

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/638505/nhg

Answer (score 0):

The `forward` method take [three parameters](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L63), the third is the query params, so try to modify the forwarding like:

```
public function secondAction($argument){
    return $this->forward('Bundle:Controller:first',array(),array('argument'=>$argument));
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the response, but is not what I'm looking for.
What I wonder is to preserve the route, to let it persist through forwardings, because no other Request takes place, and makes no sense this lose.