# Symfony2 Sending RedirectResponse from Before Filter

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using [Before Filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) to detect what language is the application using (is it english or something else, for example) and then doing some stuff with it. After I've done that stuff, I would like to send a RedirectResponse to another Symfony route like this...

```
return new RedirectResponse(route_name)
```

but that doesn't work beacuse I'm not extending ContainerAware so the component that is getting the `RedirectResponse` object doesn't know what to do with it.

My question is, how to redirect from a before filter after I'm done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some question related answer: [Symfony2 redirect for event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916439/symfony2-redirect-for-event-listener) 
Elnur Abdurrakhimov's answer or NHG's anwer would be helpful for you.

Comment: Was midway through typing pretty much exactly the same. `Google is your friend!`

Comment: I found that answer, but for some cosmic definded reason, skipped NHG's answer. Thanks