# How to make a redirection in a Listener

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to make a redirection in a Listener but it's doesn't work .

My Listener:

```
<?php
// AuthenticationListener.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationFailureEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AuthenticationListener
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event)
    {
        if(preg_match("/m\/login/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
            // var_dump('Hello'); die();
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('mobile_login'));
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        if(preg_match("/m\/login/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
           return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('mobile_home'));
        }
    }
}
```

I need this because, I've 2 login forms: one for PC, one for mobile. So if the user make a mistake with his login/pass i need to display the correct page */login* or */m/login*.

My script works. If I uncomment `var_dump('Hello');` I see the "Hello". All working good except my redirection. I've no idea why. I've no error, symfony just don't care and redirect me to */login*. Apparently it's 'normal' i'm not alone with this problem but I can't found a solution. I just read somewhere I need a Dispacher but I've no idea how it's work.

If you have a solution that would be great.

**Edit**

My UserBundle/[...]/service.yml

```
# authentication failure event listener
acme_user.security.authentication_failure_event_listener:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\Listener\AuthenticationListener
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.failure, method: onAuthenticationFailure }

# authentication success event listener
acme_user.security.interactive_login_listener:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\Listener\AuthenticationListener
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }
```

My UserBundle/[...]/routing.yml

```
mobile_login:
    pattern:  /m/login
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Mobile:login }
```

**Edit Abdallah Arffak**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MODO:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_MODO
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODO, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        mobile:
            pattern:  ^/m
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /m/login_check
                login_path: /m/login
                default_target_path: /m/admin
            logout:
                path:   /m/logout
                target: /

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user:  true
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000
                path:     /
                domain:   ~

    always_authenticate_before_granting: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/m/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**MobileController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class MobileController extends Controller
{

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = '';
        }

        if ($error) {
            // TODO: this is a potential security risk (see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9523)
            $error = $error->getMessage();
        }
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME);

        $csrfToken = $this->container->has('form.csrf_provider')
            ? $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
            : null;

        return $this->render('AcmeUserBundle:Mobile:login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Show how you have defined service for listener and your mobile_login route.

Comment: @jakon I edited. If you need something more tell me pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not have to pass through "Listener"
the best method is to pass through security

security.yml :

```
firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    mobile:
        pattern:  ^/m
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /m/login_check
            login_path: /m/login
            default_target_path: /m/admin
        logout:
            path:   /m/logout
            target: /

    main:
        pattern:  ^
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            default_target_path: /admin
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/m/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

routing.yml :

```
mobile_login:
    pattern:  /m/login
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Mobile:login  }

mobile_check_special:
    pattern:  /m/login_check

mobile_logout_special:
    pattern:  /m/logout
```

Comment: Same, I go to m/login, enter bad login and i'm redirect to /login with the error message. I edited my first post with my complete security.yml

Comment: Can you show me the code of action => AcmeUserBundle:Mobile:login

Comment: No it's good i'm an idiot, forget to change `<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">` to `<form action="{{ path("mobile_check_special") }}" method="post">`

Answer (score 2):

try something like this, Not tested:

security.yml:

```
...

firewalls:
    some_area:
        ...

        form_login:
            failure_handler: custom.security.authentication_failure_handler
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check

        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

...
```

AuthenticationFailureHandler.php

```
class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{

    private $router;

    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel, HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, LoggerInterface $logger = null, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        parent::__construct($httpKernel, $httpUtils, $options, $logger);

        $this->router = $router;
    }

    ....

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {

        if(preg_match("/m\/login/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
            return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->router->generate('mobile_login'));
        }

        return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

service config:

```
....

<service id="custom.security.authentication_failure_handler" class="%custom.security.authentication_failure_handler.class%" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.http_utils" />
    <argument type="collection" />
    <argument type="service" id="logger"  on-invalid="ignore" />
    <argument type="service" id="router" />
</service>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your service declaration like this:

```
services:
myservice:
    class: My\MyBundle\MyService
    arguments: [ @router ]
    scope: request
```

I think you missed the scope property.

Comment: get an error : InactiveScopeException: You cannot create a service ("acme.security.authentication_failure_event_listener") of an inactive scope ("request").

Comment: can you add lazy: true in the end of the service declaration and try again !

Comment: remove the scope and lazy options and change your response like this : 
 public function onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event)
    {
        if(preg_match("/m\/login/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){ 
          $url = $this->router->generate('mobile_login');
          $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
          $event->setResponse($response);
     }

Comment: take a look at this post i think you have to add onKernelController function also: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916439/symfony2-redirect-for-event-listener