# Symfony2 check logged user property, current route, and redirect

Tags: symfony, listeners

I'm looking for best place to put my logic for checking if logged user has specific property and check what is the current route. Based on this I would like to redirect user to specific route.

My User extends Sonata User and has extra method like:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasProperty()
    {
        ...
```

Moreover, I have a routes:

```
route_a:
    pattern: /a
route_b:
    pattern: /b
```

and if:

```
if ($user->hasProperty() && $currentRoute == 'route_a') {
    redirectTo('route_b');
}
if (!$user->hasProperty() && $currentRoute != 'route_a') {
    redirectTo('route_a');
}
```

I tried to do that in listener for kernel.controller event and in this listener I called something like init() controller method and I put that logic in this method. It's works fine, but I cannot redirect response.

What is the best place for this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution : [Redirect if the user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487557/symfony-2-redirect-if-the-user-is-logged-in)

You must create a Listener class in a Bundle and define this listener as a service.